# LESS translates css color tags to hexcode in list / variable

Tags: css, arrays, list, less

I have a list in less with color codes:

```
@brand-device-colors: black #000000, white #ffffff, gray #dddddd, customcolor #111222, customcolor2 #123123
```

That list goes to a function:

```
.make-device-colors(@i: length(@brand-device-colors)) when (@i > 0) {
    .make-device-colors(@i - 1);
    @color-array: extract(@brand-device-colors, @i);
    @device-color: extract(@color-array, 1);
    @device-color-code: extract(@color-array, 2);
    @device-class: ~"color-@{device-color}";

    .select-styled label {
        // Just to dump the variable
        margin: @device-class;
    }
}
.make-device-colors();
```

Output for the first element (black #000000) is:

```
.select-styled label {
    margin: color-#000000
}
```

instead of:

```
.select-styled label {
    margin: color-black
}
```

Output for customcolor is:

```
.select-styled label {
    margin: color-customcolor
}
```

LESS already translate "black" to "#000000" in my variable.
How can i prevent that? Thanks!